# VirtualRepeat in angular-material not loading any item

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using the [infiniteScrolling](https://github.com/angular/material/tree/v1.0.0/src/components/virtualRepeat/demoInfiniteScroll) demo from angular-material. I have implemented in my project but never it's executing this.infiniteItems.

What am I doing wrong?

index.html:

```
   <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
            <div layout="row" md-on-demand  md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.infiniteItems" class="repeated-item" flex>
                {item}
            </div>
   </md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('murnow')
.controller('LastReviewsCtrl', ['$scope', 'lastReviews','configMurnow', 'Reviews',
function($scope, lastReviews,configMurnow, Reviews) {



        $scope.cdn = configMurnow.cdn_domain_name;
        $scope.enviroment = configMurnow.enviroment;


        this.infiniteItems = {
          numLoaded_: 0,
          toLoad_: 0,
          // Required.
          getItemAtIndex: function(index) {
            if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
              this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
              return null;
            }
            return index;
          },
          // Required.
          // For infinite scroll behavior, we always return a slightly higher
          // number than the previously loaded items.
          getLength: function() {
            return this.numLoaded_ + 5;
          },
          fetchMoreItems_: function(index) {
                // For demo purposes, we simulate loading more items with a timed
                // promise. In real code, this function would likely contain an
                // $http request.

                if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
                    this.toLoad_ += 20;
                    Reviews.getBatch(toLoad_).then(function(data){
                        this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;

                    }).catch(function(err){

                    });
                }





            }
         }  
}]);
```

EDIT:

Here is the ui-router state:

```
  .state('lastreviews', {  
  url: '/lastreviews',
  templateUrl: 'last_reviews/_last_reviews.html',
  controller: 'LastReviewsCtrl as ctrl',
  resolve: {
    lastReviews: ['Reviews','$stateParams', function(Reviews, $stateParams){        
        return Reviews.getBatch(0);

    }]
  }
 })
```

Why infiniteItems is not executing? I don't get any error in the console.

Comment: Do you have ng-app and ng-controller like this in the container of your index.html ? ................     

     <div ng-controller="LastReviewsCtrl as ctrl"  ng-app="YourAppName">

Comment: What is your Reviews? Try remove line `Reviews.getBatch(toLoad_).then(function(data){` and your  `catch`, then run again.

Comment: @kgfaith index.html is a view loaded with ui-router I have the ng-app and the ng-controller.

Comment: @DieuNQ Reviews is a $http service. If I remove Reviews.getBatch it's still not working.

Comment: Can you put your code online? Because I don't see any problems with your code (compare to demo code [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat))

Comment: @DieuNQ I have added the ui-router state I think I don't have more code that can interfere with the controller.